# Write polynomial as irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

> Write $f(x) = x^{5} + 2x^{2} + 2x + 2$ as a product of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x], \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x], \mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]$.

I tried using the Factor Theorem but I couldn't find any zeroes in the respective rings.

Comment: There is a root $\pmod 7$, at least, since $1+2+2+2\equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

Comment: Sorry missed that one. It was $f(1)$. I'll go from there with (mod 7). Thank your for pointing that out.

Comment: In cases where there is no root, the only possible factorings would be quadratic times cubic.  A little tedious, but not actually difficult.

Comment: Do you mean i.e. $f(x) = (x^{2} + ax + b)(x^{3} + cx^{2} + dx + e)$ for $a, b, c, d, e$ in the respective ring? I tried that then one receives a system of equations. I was stuck somewhere there. I'll try that approach again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  It's really the only way to go.  Computer algebra handles these things very well, though if this is homework you'll probably want to sort it out by hand.